# form field of type managed file cause error:- EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids()

Tags: forms

```
$form['field_image'] = array(
'#type' => 'managed_file',
'#name' => 'field_image',
'#title' => t('Block image'),
```

//  '#description' => t("Image should be less than 400 pixels wide and in JPG format."),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  );

Comment: I think we'd need a little more information in order to help. Can you give us some context around the error and what you're trying to do?